# SICStus Prolog: FFI slow, how to calculate Hamming weight fast?

Tags: prolog, ffi, hamming-distance, sicstus-prolog, hammingweight

When I ran the [foreign code sample `c1/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Foreign-Code-Examples.html#Foreign-Code-Examples), as shown in the SICStus Prolog 4.3.2 manual, and compared its runtime to the corresponding Prolog code `Y is X+9`, I got strange timing results:

```
p(N, X) :- ( true1G, X is N+9, false ; X is N+9 ).

q(N, X) :- ( true1G, c1(N,X),  false ; c1(N,X)  ).

true10. true10. true10. true10. true10. true10. true10. true10. true10. true10.

true1k :- true10, true10, true10.

true1M :- true1k, true1k.

true1G :- true1M, true1k.
```

With the JIT enabled I observed:

```
| ?- call_time(p(11,X), T_p).
X = 20, T_p = 17580 ? ;                     % Prolog code
no
| ?- call_time(q(11,X), T_q).
X = 20, T_q = 66950 ? ;                     % C code
no
```

After turning off the JIT (`SP_JIT=disabled`), the timing changed like this:

```
| ?- call_time(p(11,X), T_p).
X = 20, T_p = 19650 ? ;                     % Prolog code
no
| ?- call_time(q(11,X), T_q).               
X = 20, T_q = 55840 ? ;                     % C code
no
```

Even without proper error handling and support of big integers, the C code runs almost 4x as long as the JITted Prolog code. Turning the JIT off changes the timing numbers somewhat but the big picture stays the same.

How can I speed up Hamming weight calculations in SICStus?
SWI has a dedicated arithmetic function,  [`popcount/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=f(popcount/1)), but
SICStus doesn't appear to support it (yet)...

Comment: On the speed penalty for calling C from Prolog: There is a fixed, rather large, overhead when going from Prolog to C. A lot of Prolog-state must be saved away in case the C code does something with Prolog data. So, it is not surprising that a C call is much slower than a single is/2.